# Google Apps Script - remove parts of text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a list of values in a Google Spreadsheet.

```
Color Red
Color Blue
Color Green
```

as plain text. Is it possible to edit all those cells to remove the `"Color "` via Google Apps Script?

Comment: Yes, it is, but it could also be done by formula.  Do you require that it be done with a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a formula solution would be easier:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Color ","")`

But if you want to **overwrite** the values with the new ones then I guess Google Apps Script is the only way to go:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`);
  const values = sh.getRange(`A1:A${sh.getLastRow()}`).getValues().flat();
  const new_values = values.map(v=>[v.replace(`Color `,``)]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,new_values.length,1).setValues(new_values);
}
```

Don’t forget to change the name of the sheet. In my case it is `Sheet1` and also adjust the range to your needs. In my example, I start from column A and first cell until the last row with content and then I overwrite the same exact column.

Answer (score 0):

*You can also use this, as an alternative to the solution already provided:*

```
function myColor() {
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    let vals = sheet.getRange("ROW", "COLUMN", "NO_OF_ROWS", 1).getValues()
    let regEx = new RegExp(/^[^\s]+/);
    for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
        if (regEx.exec(vals[i][0])[0] === "Color")
            sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(vals[i][0].split(' ').slice(1));
}
```

The above solution makes use of regular expressions in order to check if the first word of each cell is "Color" and if the condition checks, it removes it by making use of the `split` and `slice` methods.

For retrieving the values, the `getRange()` method has been used in order to get the range, followed by the `getValues()` in order to get the values.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [JavaScript - split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split);
- [JavaScript - slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).